# Manually reorder columns to specific location Spark 3 / Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DataFrame with over 100 columns. There are a handful of columns I'd like to move to the very left of the DataFrame. Is there an easy way to specify which columns I'd like to move to the left and then the remaining columns stay in the same order? I know I can use `select` to reorder the columns, but given that I have over 100 columns I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoders, SparkSession}
import spark.implicits._

case class D(
    C1: String,
    C2: String,
    C3: String,
    C4: String,
    C5: String,
    C6: String,
    C7: String,
    C8: String,
    C9: String,
    C10: String
)
val schema: StructType    = Encoders.product[D].schema
val fields = schema.fieldNames
// or fields = DataFrame.columns ...

val source = Seq(
  D("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"),
  D("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2"),
  D("3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3")
).toDF()

source.printSchema()
//    root
//    |-- C1: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- C2: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- C3: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- C4: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- C5: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- C6: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- C7: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- C8: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- C9: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- C10: string (nullable = true)
source.show()
//    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
//    | C1| C2| C3| C4| C5| C6| C7| C8| C9|C10|
//    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
//    |  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|
//    |  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|
//    |  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|
//    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

val colFirst = Array("C1", "C2", "C10", "C7")
val tmpLast = fields.diff(colFirst)
val cols = colFirst ++ tmpLast

val res1 = source.select(cols.head, cols.tail:_*)
res1.printSchema()
//    root
//    |-- C1: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- C2: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- C10: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- C7: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- C3: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- C4: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- C5: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- C6: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- C8: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- C9: string (nullable = true)

res1.show(false)
//    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
//    |C1 |C2 |C10|C7 |C3 |C4 |C5 |C6 |C8 |C9 |
//    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
//    |1  |1  |1  |1  |1  |1  |1  |1  |1  |1  |
//    |2  |2  |2  |2  |2  |2  |2  |2  |2  |2  |
//    |3  |3  |3  |3  |3  |3  |3  |3  |3  |3  |
//    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: I think it is basically what I need, but quite a few of my columns have `.` in them. For example, `ex.test`. Because of this the column string needs to have a backtick in it, but when I use dataframe.columns, I don't get these backticks so when I call `select` it fails.

Comment: Actually I can just add backticks to all columns using `map`. Then this works.

Comment: see foldLeft...